# Join SQL query optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I've been trying to improve performance of my query which is executing quite a long time. I've already checked explain plan and it looks ok (two nested loops, usage of index)
Can you spot any improvement possibilities? Maybe some of the functions I'm using aren't too fast? Or maybe its just a problem of large data set and there is not much I can do?
Thanks for any advice!

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
  TRUNC(a_tab.some_date) ,
  TO_CHAR(MIN(a_tab.some_date),'dd/MM/YYYY HH24:mm:ss') ,
  TO_CHAR(MAX(a_tab.some_date),'dd/MM/YYYY HH24:mm:ss')
FROM TABLE_A a_tab
JOIN TABLE_B b_tab
ON a_tab.id              = b_tab.a_tab_id
where b_tab.keyword_name = 'NAME_X'
AND b_tab.keyword_value  = 'VALUE_X'
AND a_tab.some_date BETWEEN to_date('01/05/2014','dd/MM/YYYY') AND to_date('01/06/2014','dd/MM/YYYY')
AND extract (hour FROM a_tab.some_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 13
GROUP BY TRUNC(a_tab.some_date)
ORDER BY TRUNC(a_tab.some_date);
```

Comment: Please share the execution plan and some key information like number of rows in table_a and table_b, and how selective the predicates are. Also, how long is "quite some time" and what duration do you consider acceptable?

Comment: table_a is 44371435 rows and table_b 88837780 and runs for over an hour (70mins) for interval of one month

Comment: explain plan: http://tinypic.com/r/fnb635/8

Comment: Next step is: how selective is each predicate. So, how selective is "b_tab.keyword_name = 'NAME_X'" and "b_tab.keyword_value = 'VALUE_X'" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Index could help this query, but it can be hard to tell which ones because you are filtering on both tables.  Here are two to try:

```
table_b(keyword_name, keyword_value, a_tab_id)
table_a(some_date, id)
```

I would try the one on `table_b` first.

However, given the size of the tables that you are joining, it is possible that the query might take a long time.  One table has 44 million rows and the other 88 million.  If the `where` clauses are not selective, then Oracle has to process a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT /*+ FULL(A_TAB) */ ...` to determine if one of the indexes is not efficient.  If that helps then it may be worth investigating why Oracle is choosing the index over a full table scan.  Maybe statistics need to be regathered or perhaps a parameter like OPTIMIZER_INDEX_COST_ADJ is set to an unusual value like 1.

Btree indexes are only useful when selecting a small percentage of rows.  Every value retrieved from an index range scan requires traversing a tree data structure, one block at a time.  That's ideal for selecting a small amount of data.  For a large amount of data a full table scan with multi-block IO is much faster.  Reading an entire month of data may be "too much" data for an index.

Btree indexes can also be inefficient in some cases if the index clustering factor is poor.  Oracle retrieves data one block at a time, usually 8 KB of data.  If the data is physically stored in a random order then selecting 1% of the rows may require reading 100% of the blocks.

Indexes aren't always the answer, that's why Oracle has hash joins.